# reboot after shutdown Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, reboot, wakeup, wakeonlan

After shutdown the system restarts in 5 seconds

I tried a lot solutions for this problem:
 - Wake on LAN - it is down now

```
Settings for enp5s0:
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 10Mb/s
Duplex: Half
Port: MII
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: d
Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
               drv probe ifdown ifup
```

Also I disabled everything in wake up

```
cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
LANC      S5    *disabled
EHC1      S0    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S0    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.0
XHC   S0    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.0
PCIB      S5    *disabled
RP02      S4    *disabled
ECF0      S4    *disabled
RP03      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.2
RP04      S5    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.3
WNIC      S5    *disabled  pci:0000:04:00.0
RP06      S5    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.5
NIC   S5    *disabled  pci:0000:05:00.0
RP07      S4    *disabled
RP08      S0    *disabled
HST1      S5    *disabled
```

But problem persists

Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check your BIOS settings. everytime I've had this issue it was because of bios settings. In fact a foolproof solution would be to use your BIOS's reset functionality.

Tell me if this worked, cheers!

Comment: Made it by "restore default" option in my bios - problem is not resolved

Comment: type `sudo shudown` into a terminal does it still reboot?

Comment: sorry for long time away, yes I did it - the same result

Comment: How is that not a hardware issue then? how can software trigger the hardware to turn on by itself? check all bios options for anything unusual, if you could edit your post to accomodate pictures of all your BIOS menus, check for faulty hardware.  The power button or reset button or something else could be faulty/stuck/experiencing static or short circuits. And most importanly power down the PSU or unplug the computer from the wall completely wait 20 seconds plug it back in and see if it turns on by itself.

Comment: With hardware everything should be okay. There was a Windows two days ago and all were ok.

link to photo of bios:
https://goo.gl/photos/gQpDZjFm4QSeEznW8

Comment: try unticking all those boot options : USB floppy ect. and try the unplugging test i mentioned above.

Comment: I did what you say.
I turn off laptop with poweroff button it will not start.

also I found in bios Wake-on-Lan option and turn off it.
Situation now: for suspend it is work ok. Laptop is going to sleep and does not start till I press the button. But for shutdown it is reboot

Comment: did you try unplugging the power cord waiting 20 seconds then plugging it back in? does it turn on by itself? if not once you turned it on yourself and try to shutdown does it still turn on?

Comment: I tried unplugging the power cord. But I could not wait 20 seconds because it started to turning on. Should I turn off battery? 

If I try to shutdown when power cord is connected - as result will be reboot

Comment: oh, it's a laptop! yeah remove the batery as well. the goal of this exrcise is to discharge the components and see if as soon as current is available again it takes that as a cue to turn on.

Comment: So, what I did now: 1. turn off laptop 2. remove battery 3. Wait 30 second 4. Install battery. Result I do nothing but it started to turning on in 3-5 seconds

Comment: see that's what i meant. ubuntu is now guaranteed to be entirely absent from fault. This is now with 100% certainty a hardware issue. Powered down soft (even that concept is false) cannot issue current signal to the motherboard. It cannot turn the computer on. update your OP with every screen from your BIOS photographed.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved 
In all questions (Wake on lan) I saw only with command

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol d
```

But full instruction is here [Disabling ‘Wake On LAN’ in Ubuntu](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/09/disabling-wake-on-lan-in-ubuntu-might-save-a-tiny-bit-of-power-on-your-laptop/)

Now everething work correct