# Ubuntu 18.04 reboot after shutdown

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, shutdown, reboot

I'm experiencing this strange issue for some time now (before my 18.04 upgrade).

When I shutdown my computer it reboots right away.
I searched the web and tried a lot of suggestions, nothing worked.

I tried `sudo shutdown` no difference
I have a dual boot, when I shutdown **on Windows**, the computer **shuts down and doesn't reboot**.

I tried sur solution suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908606/ubuntu-16-04-reboot-after-shutdown), I don't have that /etc/grub/module file, and the first part didn't work as well.

I tried to disable WOL as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914394/reboot-after-shutdown-ubuntu-16-04). Didn't work either.

If you have any extra suggestion, I'll gladly try them.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I have begun to have the exact same issue.

Comment: no solution found so far...

Comment: Thanks! I found that unplugging my lan cable prevents the reboot, even though  wake on lan is disabled.

Comment: I will try that, but it is not what I call a solution :/

Comment: My computer is still rebooting with the lan cable unplugged.